# I am having a server running problem in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

When running my project with Express js "
I got an error saying "I am having a server running problem in Nodejs. How can I solve it.

```js
const router = require('express').Router()

// all product
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('all product')
})

// get product
router.get('/:productID', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`$(req.params.productID) id ile gelen urun`)
})

router.post('/create', (req, res) => {
  res.send('product created')
})

router.patch('/:productID', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`$(req.params.productID) product update`)
})

router.delete('/:productID', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`$(req.params.productID) prdoduct delete`)
}) 

module.export = router
```

Comment: Provide the exact error message, do not paraphrase.

Comment: We can't help you until you provide more detailed information on exactly what the error message is, what code it occurs in and then a more complete description of exactly what you need help with.  Your question is accumulating both close votes and down votes because it is not clear enough for anyone to be able to help you.  You need to provide a more complete description of the problem before anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `module.exports = router` instead of `module.export = router`